# Make user agent change permanent on Safari for Windows

Tags: windows, safari, user-agent

If I change my Safari user agent using the **Develop > User Agent** menu in the browser, the change does not persist between tabs. I know that this command exists on Mac OS to permanently change your user agent:

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari CustomUserAgent "\"useragentstring\""
```

Does anyone know of an equivalent command on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an entry to the defaults.plist file - it's in Program Files/Safari/Safari.resources and can be viewed with a text editor - it's XML-like.

Key is CustomUserAgent, string is your user agent string.

I've heard some people saying the plist edits aren't reliable, but they seem to be working for me, anyway.